# How should I get the Request in ApiController constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

**Task**
I have a DataMapper class that I use to map data into custom representations for my web api's mobile client.

```
public class DataMapper
    {
        public static string Role { get; set; }
        public static RoleReturnModel Create(IdentityRole appRole)
        {
            return new RoleReturnModel
            {
                Id = appRole.Id,
                Name = appRole.Name
            };

        }
        public static CountryReturnModel Create(Country country)
        {
            return new CountryReturnModel
            {
                Id = country.Id,
                Name = country.Name,
                CityList = country.Cities.Select(city => DataMapper.Create(city))
            };

        }
        public static CityReturnModel Create(City city)
        {
            return new CityReturnModel
            {
                Id = city.Id,
                Name = city.Name,
            };

        }
}
```

The first property as you can see is called Role. I need to populate that with whichever role is accessing my web method. This is so because at times I need conditional mapping to return role specific data representations to the client.

**Problem**
I thought the best place to do DataMapper.Role = CurrentRole would be in the constructor of my ApiController

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    private ModelFactory _modelFactory;
    private ApplicationUserManager _AppUserManager = null;
    private ApplicationRoleManager _AppRoleManager = null;

    protected BaseApiController()
    {
       //Request is null here
        DataMapper.Role = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>().FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Name; 
    }
```

This however doesn't work . The Request object is null in the constructor. It only gets filled in my actual web method

```
public class UsersController : BaseApiController
{

    IUserRepository UserRepository;
    public UsersController() // will use ninject for constructor injection
    {
        UserRepository = new UserRepository();
    }

    [Route("profile")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser()
    {
         //Request is available here
    }
```

I am a webapi noobie. Need pointers to this problem.

Comment: The request is not available as yet in the constructor. You can only access it in an action/method after the controller has already been initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request is not available as yet in the constructor. You can only access it in an action/method after the controller has already been initialized.

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController {
    private ModelFactory _modelFactory;
    private ApplicationUserManager _AppUserManager = null;
    private ApplicationRoleManager _AppRoleManager = null;

    protected string GetRole() {
        return Request.GetOwinContext()
            .GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
            .FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Name;     
    }
```

And accessed

```
public class UsersController : BaseApiController {

    IUserRepository UserRepository;
    public UsersController() // will use ninject for constructor injection
    {
        UserRepository = new UserRepository();
    }

    [Route("profile")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUser()
    {
         //Request is available here
        var role = GetRole();
    }
```

Or consider extracting that out into an extension method so that it can be reused

```
var role = this.GetUserRole();
```

Where

```
public static string GetUserRole(this ApiController controller) {
    var request = controller.Request;
    var user = controller.User
    return request.GetOwinContext()
        .GetUserManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
        .FindById(user.Identity.GetUserId()).Name;     
}
```

Comment: Thanks nkosi however that doesn't quite solve my problem. 

I need to inject the role into my custom DataMapper class at just once place. 

The strategy you suggest would have no to written in every web method no?

Comment: Both the request and User are not available in the constructor. There is very little place else you can get access to them.